# Artifactory API AQL with Jenkins environment variables

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, artifactory, aql

I try to perform the following code in a postbuild Jenkins task:

```
curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:***********" -X POST https://artifactory_url/artifactory/api/search/aql -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d 'items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"REPO"},"name":{"$match":"*${env.SUBSYSTEM}*"},"name":{"$nmatch":"*pdf*"}}).include("repo","name","path")'
```

(Here it is broken up over several lines for readability):

```
curl -X POST https://artifactory_url/artifactory/api/search/aql \
     -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:***********" \
     -H "Content-Type: text/plain" \
     -d 'items.find( \
         {"repo":{"$eq":"REPO"}, \
          "name":{"$match":"*${env.SUBSYSTEM}*"}, \
          "name":{"$nmatch":"*pdf*"}}).include("repo","name","path")'
```

This is not working because the environment variable `${env.SUBSYSTEM}` is not solved. Is there anyway for use variables in curl with the aql?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 2):

It's probably not resolving the environment variable because you're wrapping that piece of string in single quotes (`'`), which preserve the literal value of each character within the quotes (meaning variables aren't resolved). You could use double quotes (`"`) with escaping, which would look like:

```
... -d "items.find({\"repo\":{\"$eq\":\"REPO\"},\"name\":{\"$match\":\"*${env.SUBSYSTEM}*\"},\"name\":{\"$nmatch\":\"*pdf*\"}}).include(\"repo\",\"name\",\"path\")"
```

Or possibly just break the environment variable out of the quoting:

```
... -d 'items.find({"repo":{"$eq":"REPO"},"name":{"$match":"*'${env.SUBSYSTEM}'*"},"name":{"$nmatch":"*pdf*"}}).include("repo","name","path")'
```

Comment: Yeah right! Thx bto, the second option was a great solution